[GCP][BQ]Asking for bigquery.datasets.update on source for creating view
Since a few days now it seems I cannot create a view that need to read another view in another dataset when I don't have bigquery.datasets.update on the dataset.
Explanation :

I have a table random_project.dataset_src.table
I have a view pointing to the previous table : random_project.dataset_src.view
When I try to create a view in my_project.dataset using the view random_project.dataset_src.view it throws : Access Denied: Dataset random_project:dataset_src: Permission bigquery.datasets.update denied on dataset random_project:dataset_src (or it may not exist).

Create Or Replace View my_project.dataset.my_view As
Select
    [...]
From random_project.dataset_src.view
;

I only needed dataview for this operation before, I don't see why I should have update permission on the dataset of another project. Is the error message not accurate ? Is there a new security policy on BQ ?
I have check dataviewer permissions and didn't ask for update permission tho as it might be a sensitive right
Thank you for you help.
Regards

I get the same error when trying on a table : random_project.dataset_src.table

Hi @Elioz, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

The answer was actually in the documentation when dataset are authorized you need bigquery.datasets.update permission to add the view in the authorized view. It does not do that when the dataset you are trying to create the view is not listed in the authorized datasets.
